# Changing directory in ubuntu with Ruby and a command line tool

Tags: ruby, shell, ubuntu, command-line

```
#!/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby

 case ARGV[0]
        when "apache"
                exec('cd /etc/apach2')
                exec('sudo nano httpd.conf')

        #...
 end
```

I am trying to make a quick command line tool that will change directories for me with one word.. so from the command line (in ubuntu 12). It tells me it cant cd.. But I try the command myself and it will work just fine.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the `alias` command as outlined here: http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/  ? Are you looking to chain commands? Can you show the actual command line errors? i.e. copy and paste it to your question.

Comment: /home/user/bin/test.rb:5:in `exec': No such file or directory - cd (Errno::ENOENT)
 from /home/user/bin/test.rb:5:in `<main>'

Comment: Also, I would rather just know how to do it in ruby.. I want to manipulate system output and write more complex commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I did this and it works (I'm on OS X but should be the same):

```
ARGV[0]
  when "testme"
    system('cd ripple')
    system('ls -al')

    #...
end
```

calling `system('cd ...` does not change move you to that directory in the current shell you are executing your .rb file in. So it would make more sense to do:

```
system('sudo nano /etc/....
```

all on one line

I tested it with back ticks and it didn't work at all for me.

I tested with `exec()` and got the expected result, it runs one line and that's it. So `exec()` could work if you only have one command to run or you chain them all together with `&&`

```
exec('ls /etc && sudo nano /etc/....
```

I would read this: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Comment: Should'nt that be "case c" ?

Comment: Also note, when I run this it just executes each one separately. i.e. it does `cd...` but then it does `ls -al` on the directory I am in NOT the one I asked it to CD to.

Comment: of course you don't have to cd to the directory to run the command, so I would change your original to a one line: `sudo nano /etc/apach2/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's Dir class is your friend for this, check-out the [`chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) method:

```
Dir.chdir('/path/to/change/to')
```

will change Ruby's concept of the current working directory for the time the code is running. Any sub-shells would consider that their starting directory.

You can also pass [`chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) a block, and all code in that block will assume the new directory, which will then revert to the old one when the block exits:

```
Dir.chdir('/path/to/change/to') do
  # do some stuff
end
```